# Which ranged champion has the highest damage wave clear ability in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which ranged champion has the highest attack damage wave clear potential in League of Legends?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear because all ADCs have a strong focus on last-hitting and earning gold that way (since they scale primarily based on their items). Are you asking which ADCs have the best waveclear? Or which ones can harass the best (thus preventing the enemy laner from CSing properly)? Or which one can survive being poked while still last hitting? Each champion has their own niche - there's no "best" champion for such a broad goal as "farming gold".

Comment: I want to clarify that I mean minion kills from early to mid game. Wave clear abilities would be a good measurement of performance. I understand minion kills depends on each game and the player's ability. I am curious if somebody has tried several ranged champions to farm and what their experiences were.

To clarify:

Who is the ranged champion with the best wave clear to farm gold bottom lane in League of Legends?

Comment: That's still not really being very specific. ADCs primary purpose in the early game is to farm minions. Some ADCs do this by clearing waves very quickly by hitting multiple minions at once (Sivir, Jinx) while others focus on doing a lot of damage to single minions at a time (Draven, Vayne). During laning phase, each side is going to be spawning the same number of minions, so really the only differentiating factor is harass and positioning, and maybe how easy it is to farm under turret.

Comment: I don't think this question could be answered clearly. There are too many factors to account for that may hinder or improve your CSing. Ganks, harass, fights and misplays all prevent or help you in terms of CS. The item "Cull" grants you gold after killing 100 minions, which further muddies up the issue. In a way, the best way to farm gold in bottom lane would be to just kill the enemy and take their turret first.

Comment: I agree. There are a lot of factors.

I was watching a League of Legends Last Hitting guide on YouTube and it was discussing controversy over destroying the enemy tower and its effect on minion kills. The player was saying it's better for minion kills to leave the enemy tower alive and herd enemy minions around the sweet spot near and outside the range of our own tower (which would take minion kills) and inside the sweet spot our champion is safer than further into the lane on the enemy side.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the old question. Definitely falls under the category of good subjective question that can be answered by someone who plays or has experience with the game.

Comment: To continue with how there are many factors in gold generation in the game, a reason to destroy the enemy tower and push their lane is to create pressure to draw enemies to that lane. You can push the wave and rotate to another lane in an attempt to gain an objective or kill elsewhere. Doing so will get you more gold, usually.

Comment: I'll try your strategy. I haven't tried it before. I've been trying farming strategies that are defensive like poking enemy champions and guarding the minions by placing Caitlyn's Yordle Snap Traps where the enemy champions would stand, so I can last hit.

Heimerdinger was doing the best at minion kills in one match.

Comment: You have to understand, a champion's waveclear ability is really based on YOUR skill with that champ. Assuming you want to get the last hit for each minion, you need to know when you can spare another auto before last hitting the cannon, etc. You have to be used to a given champion's early game AS and damage.

Comment: The OP clearly mentioned waveclear, using auto attacks is one of the slowest ways to clear a wave in LoL. Don't assume it's adcs only.

Comment: This question seems to be asking two different things. To me it feels like an attempt to make a subjective question look objective, and looking at the edit history confirms this. Wave clear does not necessarily relate to efficient farming in lane. As such, I am going to edit the question to remove farming entirely.

Answer (score 8):

There isn't really a "best" marksman to farm with. Almost all ranged AD champions have the advantage of getting easy last hits due to the fact that they build AD and have basically unlimited resources due to the fact that they don't spend any mana on their "main attack", however there are some that have certain advantages.

Since there are usually two people (Marksman and support) on bot there are certain situations where different champions excel at farming while others are struggling. Therefore I will look at two main aspects of farming: The **ability to farm** minions and the **safety** while doing so.

In general there are a few things that contribute to the ability of a marksman to farm well. These are:

**Attack speed buffs**
These help in pretty much every situation. It just makes it plain easier to last hit and leaves more room for error since you might be able to add in a second hit if you screwed up your last.
Notable examples are Jinx, Varus and Ezreal

**High range**
High range makes it extremely safe to last hit and it allows for easy switching between harrassing and farming. 
Notable examples are Jinx, Caitlyn and Ashe

**Area of effect spells/Attacks**
This makes waveclearing a lot easier and especially midgame you can kill multiple minions with a single use of an AoE spell.
Notable examples are Jinx, Sivir and Varus

**Auto attack resets/Spammable abilities**
Auto attack resets or spammable abilities are similar to an increased attack speed. They allow for more errors and can be used to quickly lasthit something.
Notable examples are Ezreal, Sivir and Vayne

**Gapclosers/Defensive Spells**
Last but not least we have gapclosers. This is again something that doesn't directly affect farming, however if you have the extra safety of a gapcloser you can usually go in for more risky creeps without getting punished too hard by the enemies. 
Notable examples are Ezreal, Sivir and Kalista

Based on the factors above it's possible to narrow down the "best" farmers. Obviously these champions will perform differently based on mastery of the champion and the situation they're in but it's pretty safe to say that the following champions are extremely strong, safe or both while farming on bottom.

**Jinx**
Probably one of the strongest. She has AOE, high range, low mana cost, attack speed steroids and minor defensive spells. Her only real disatvantage is the fact that she doesn't have any gapclosers.

**Sivir**
Sivir has extremely strong waveclear while also staying relatively safe with her spellshield. She also has an auto attack reset and an attack speed buff past lvl 6. Her disadvantage is her low range and lack of gapclosers.

**Ezreal**
For people who are familiar with lasthitting as an ADC this will probably be the safest of all. You have a free flash every 6-10 seconds and a spammable Q plus an attack speed passive. The only disadvantage there is is the high skill cap of the champion.

**Caitlyn**
She's kind of like a mix between Ezreal and Jinx. While she doesn't have the mobility of ezreal or the damage of Jinx she has a mix of both that make her safe and strong while farming.

As I said. There is no real best champion but most mentioned above will outperform players on the same skill level that aren't playing those champs.

Comment: You are forgetting Twitch who can clear a wave in a few auto attacks with the help of his stacks.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for then please click on the checkmark on the left side. It is the best way to show your appreciation!

Comment: Sivir kinda has a gap closer, with her ultimate.

Comment: @ShadowZ. a movespeed buff isn't considered a gap closer. a gap closer would be a blink, dash, jump, etc

Comment: @jutschge based on the question asked, ezreal is not really a good fit for this list as he has abysmal wave clear ability. yes he can farm safely, but without ult/statik shiv/iceborn gauntlet, he cant really clear waves.

Comment: @Dragonrage Yeah the question got edited several times. I wrote the answer as an answer to the original post, which asked for the best champions to farm bot with. And in the hands of a skilled player Ezreal is certainly among the top 3.

Comment: @dragonrage I know, thats why I said it is "kinda". It can easily help close the gap, especially if the support has Righteous Glory and or Talisman of Ascension. But it does not qualify for a true gap closer.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ADCs that specialize in clearing waves quickly.

**Sivir** is probably the queen of wave clear when it comes to ADCs. Her Q does a lot of damage after it's been leveled a few times, plus her W will hit every single minion in a wave and can also crit (in fact, if a W-empowered auto attack crits the first target, all subsequent targets will also be crit). I have cleared 12-15 minions in about 2-3 seconds come late game with Sivir's strong AoE abilities.

**Jinx** is also very good at clearing waves quickly thanks to her rocket launcher, which deals splash damage to any units near your target. Similar to Sivir's W, if Jinx crits on her primary target, the splash damage will also crit. Runaan's Hurricane is especially strong on her, since the extra bolts that the item creates will also deal splash damage. It's very possible to clear an entire wave of minions in one or two auto attacks with Jinx.

**Graves** is a short-range AoE ADC, so it should come as no surprise that he is also decent at clearing waves. His Q, when properly placed, can deal a lot of damage to minions, plus his auto attacks on their own can hit multiple minions at once. His auto attacks also push non-champions/non-epic monsters back, which prevents them from attacking him if they are melee.

**Lucian** is very good at clearing waves because his primary damaging ability (his Q) travels through minions and does damage to anything in its path. Combined with enough cooldown reduction and his passive, he can dash around and clear a wave of minions pretty quickly. Additionally, his ult does a lot of bonus damage to minions, so it can also be good for waveclear in some situations.

**Tristana** can be okay for wave clear due to her passive, which deals a little bonus damage to any enemy units close to a unit she just killed. Additionally, her E also does a significant amount of damage in a small blast radius if fully charged. However, it has a moderately long cooldown, so she's not as good as the other champions I've listed here when it comes to waveclear.

Finally, buying Runaan's Hurricane on any ADC will give them significantly more wave-clearing power, since they will deal damage to more targets per auto attack. On some champions, this item is very important - after purchase, **Twitch**'s waveclear strength goes up quite a bit since each bolt applies a stack of his passive, which in turn boosts his E ability damage. It's a similar scenario when buying the item on **Varus**. However, Runaan's might not be the best item to buy on *every* ADC. For example, though it would help Vayne clear waves much better, it's not as optimal as something like Phantom Dancer or Rapidfire Cannon since Vayne's specialty is dueling and teamfighting, not clearing waves.

Comment: Miss Fortune wasn't mentioned, but with her passive you can switch targets to deal extra damage with each aa. You can also farm and harass at the same time with Q.

Comment: @mbomb007 I actually left out MF on purpose because, in my opinion, she's more focused on teamfighting and single/two target damage. Her E doesn't do that much damage (unless she's building AP, but then she wouldn't be the ADC) and her Q, though deadly, can only take out up to 2 minions per cast. Overall, she doesn't have waveclear as one of the main focuses of her kit, so I left her out of the answer.

Comment: Her clear speed w/ passive is good if you just look at early game, when you don't want to use mana on minions. Depends what phase of the game you look at. The OP said "early to mid game"

Comment: Kalista with hurricane is also very good at clearing waves. Use the hurricane to proc her E on several minions at once and the wave is gone. You also left out Caitlyn who can probably shove waves better than anyone in the early game, and just below her Ashe also. With their long range they are safer as well.

Comment: Caitlyn's main focus is long-range harass and zone control, not wave clear, plus her only AoE skill uses a lot of mana. Also, like I said in my answer, *any* ADC will do well waveclearing once they have Runaan's... that's the whole point of the item. It's just not optimal on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, Sivir, Caitlyn, Twitch, Jinx, Tristana, Lucian, Graves, and Ashe have good wave clear and their wave clear is generally amplified by Runaan's Huricane (doesn't help Sivir, Lucian, or Graves as much as the others), but they neglected to mention a few others who have good ranged attack damage wave clear.

**Varus** has exceptional wave clear having two abilities capable of dealing large amounts of damage to minions. If it is safe enough to auto attack a few times and you have Runaan's Hurricane, you can stack your W passive up on several minions and amplify the damage your Q or E will do to them and can usually clear a full minion wave with a few autos and a Q or E based on which you maxed first and what items you have. If you want to stay safe and clear from a far, you can use Q from max range to clear waves quite quickly from relative safety.

**Corki** is a somewhat unique pick as he does a lot of hybrid damage, but you mainly build ad on him, making him a ranged attack damage dealer who also deals a lot of magic damage. His Q and R are both high damage ranged AOE abilities and can be used to quickly clear waves along with his E ability which does AOE damage in a cone in front of Corki while it is active.

**Jhin** when using his abilities can clear waves quite quickly if he combos properly. If you use an E on the caster minions and then get a minion low enough with a few autos that your Q will kill the minion, it will deal significantly more damage on its bounces. This allows you kill minion waves fairly quickly, and your W can help as well as its damage will pass through to all minions in the line provided the shot is not blocked by a champion.

**Jayce** is both a melee and a ranged champion, and when in ranged form, he can use his Q to clear minion waves quickly with the AOE explosion around the target area. A properly aimed Q can hit multiple minions at a time, and if amplified with his E, can do considerable amounts of damage from a long range and clear minions quite quickly.

**Quinn** also has decent wave clear with her Q, as it has an AOE explosion and does quite good damage.

While not always used for wave clear, Miss Fortune, Jhin, Draven, and Twitch can use their ultimate abilities to clear a wave much faster than normal.

Besides these options for ranged champions with attack damage wave clear, many mages such as Ahri, Lux, Syndra, and Ziggs have excellent ranged magic damage wave clear.